# time stamp are resetting to Zero when changed from to_date to to_char in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to change the following sql query to the postgres format. how can I do that?

eg:

```
round((TIME_TO_SEC(testruntest.endtime) - TIME_TO_SEC(testruntest.starttime))/60,2)
```

I tried this query and got error as "time_to_sec" is not a supported function...

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL standard `EXTRACT` function:

```
EXTRACT(epoch FROM testruntest.endtime)
```

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) describes:

> For `timestamp with time zone` values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (can be negative); for `date` and `timestamp` values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 local time; for `interval` values, the total number of seconds in the interval